# WordPress function breaks widget's markup?

Tags: widgets, wp-list-pages

Here's a standard function creating widget, it displays Widget's title and echoes "test" below it:

```
 function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        extract( $args );
        $title = apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title'] );

        echo $before_widget;

        if ( $title )
            echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;

             echo 'test';

        echo $after_widget;
    }
```

It creates perfect output:

```
<li id="widgets-id" class="widget widgets-class">
   <h2 class="widgettitle">Title</h2>
   test
</li>
```

But when I replace `echo 'test';` with `wp_list_pages();` things start to look nasty because widget's body is being displayed after the tag that closes the widget:

```
  <li id="widgets-id" class="widget widgets-class">
       <h2 class="widgettitle">Title</h2>
       <!-- Hey, I wanted this data to be put here! -->
   </li>
   <li class="page_item page-item-number">
     <a href="#">Paage title</a>
   <li>
   (...)
```

Any ideas how to fix it? I've been trying with multiple wp_list_pages() arguments, but nothing seems to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wp_list_pages` does not wrap it's output in a `ul` or `ol` tag. That's up to you.

In other words, if you just call `wp_list_pages`, it's going to spit out a bunch of `li` tags, which your browser assumes is wrong and "corrects" the html as it sees fit.  Try this:

```
function widget( $args, $instance ) {
    extract( $args );
    $title = apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title'] );

    echo $before_widget;

    if ( $title )
        echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;

    echo '<ul>';
    wp_list_pages();
    echo '</ul>';

    echo $after_widget;
}
```